# Overall operation, characteristics and usage scenarios of OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++

I am a rookie in this tool (**OMNeT++**). I would like to ask you where I can find information about:

- *overall operation* of OMNeT++
- *characteristics* of OMNeT++
- *usage scenarios* of OMNeT++

Answer (score 1):

It's best to start off with the manual:
https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#toc_5

I like this page however:
https://omnetpp.org/pmwiki/?n=Main.OmnetppInNutshell

Take the time to read those. They're pretty assisting.